# rspec hook after report gets created

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there an rspec hook that runs after a report file gets created?

For example, in my `.rspec`, I have included:

```
--format json --out test_results/rspec.json
```

and I'd like to post process this file and publish metrics elsewhere. I would strongly prefer not to create a separate script, and would prefer to do this as part of my `bundle exec rspec` command. Is there an RSpec hook that would run after this file gets created?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by implementing your own formatter based on the JSON formatter. Something like this could work:

```rb
class CustomFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter 
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_started

  def close(_notification)
    super

    # Do your post processing here...
  end
end
```

And then you can use your custom formatter like this

```rb
rspec --require ./custom_formatter.rb --format CustomFormatter
```

The `RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter` is marked as private so it can change anytime. You have to think if you want to take the risk to need to change and adapt in a future RSpec upgrade.

Otherwise I would recommend to just use a custom script. It should be very simple with just `&&` or `|` in it like

```
rspec --format json | ./run_postprocessing
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/lib/rspec/core/formatters/json_formatter.rb#L56